# php get refreshed value of cookie

Tags: php

I have set cookie value using javascript and then i would like to retrieve refreshed cookie value using php...but i im getting old value of cookie..can somebody post me here solution...here is the code:

```
onClick="javascript:document.cookie='title=< ?php echo $title; ? >';"
```

and code for retrieve cookie..but is not refreshed:

```
<?php $tit=$_COOKIE['title']; ?>
```

so when i echo `$tit;` i get old value...can somebody post here solution to refresh cookie value and read it to php variable `$tit`

Comment: can you format your code properly >

Comment: onMouseDown will get called before onClick.

Comment: why not try like `<a href="ftp://<?php echo $source.'/'.$source2.'/'.$genre .'/'.$title ?>"` instead of millions of open and close php tags

Comment: PHP is server-side, I suppose you refresh your page using javascript?

Comment: Creating a cookie is a bit more complex: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 1):

As @datasage points out `onMouseDown` gets called before `onClick` so your `addHit` javascript runs before setting the cookie value.  See [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html) for details

EDIT: I get what you are trying to do now.  You will need to create another php file (datagetter.php in my example) to handle directory scanning and returning data in a useful format, I believe everything you want to do cannot happen in one file all at once without reloading the page or adding an ajax handler to the beginning of your php code.

Use php to echo your links

```
<a href="ftp://<?php echo $source . '/' . $source2 . '/' . $genre . '/' . $title ?>" id="PopUpItUp" class="detail" data-title="<?php echo $title; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $title ?> (Episodes)</a>
```

Use jQuery to attach event handlers to each link

```
<script>
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.detail').each().mousedown(function () {
        //set title cookie  access this in php with $_COOKIE['title']
        $.cookie('title', $(this).attr('data-title'));
    });
    $('.detail').each().click(function (e) {
        //increment hitcount
        var titleid = $(this).attr('data-id')
        addHit('./count.php?id=' + titleid , titleid);
        //get data to display via ajax call you may want this IN addHit somewhere
        //there will be a delay in getting the data you want so display something to show progress while we wait
        $("#popup").html("<div><img src='progresshappens.gif' width='25px' height='25px' />");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://yourdomain.com/datagetter.php?id=' + titleid,
            success: function(data) {
                //Do something with data, probably add to popup window? here is a starting point
                //Check into using javascript 'for each' function
                $('#popup').html('<div>' + data + '</div>');
            },
            error: function(request, error, errormessage) {
                //show error, something bad happened
                $("#messages").html(error + '\n' + errormessage);
            }
        });
        //don't follow link
        e.preventdefault();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: great...i have now add your modified code...and add onmousedown and onmouseup (onclick is removed now from code)...and cookie is set...but i don't know how to refresh page using php code....to read new value from cookie using                                               <?php $tit=$_COOKIE['title']; ?>

Comment: in your `addHit()` code you could call `location.refresh()`.  That will reload the page... are you sure you want that every time someone clicks a link though?  I think you could do some ajax with jQuery for a better solution.

Comment: location.refresh will reload page...this is not good solution currently for user....the point of this script is: when user click on link (link is in the following format: <u>Batman (2010)</u>) then javascript set cookie value "Batman" and then popup opens(using bpopup plugin from query) and scans folder on ftp server that have name of folder - movie name (Batman)...so i need read refreshed value of cookie to get correct folder name to scan entire files on that folder.

Comment: so if someone can post me ajax code using jQuery it will be great..my knowledge of using ajax is poor

Comment: It would help a bit to see more code how did you want to get the ftp contents? i'll edit my answer now for what I think you want but you'll probably need to add some code

Comment: Thanks for help. When user click on link then javascript write cookie value of $title; (code below that i have posted using href)...then using id="PopUpItUp" its gets to hidden div that shows popup window. here is code of that popup:

Comment: is there possible that i can insert html code into onmousedown function? like for example: onmousedown="<div> <a href="" id="PopUpItUp" </div>"   if is possible please write code examample then i don't need cookies...here is link to txt file that contains code that i have. http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=ViJyp

Comment: thanks vortextangent for code..but it is possible to insert <div> code of hidden popup window that i have attached in txt file on textuploader.com success: function(data) {
                    //Do something with data, probably add to popup window?  <--yes i would like to add here code for popup window..that is in txt file but i have html code using div and this is jquery code so i don't know how to add html code inside this function success. Many Thanks all for your help..i im waiting for code...thanks again.

Comment: i updated my answer to get you started in the right direction i think.  Everything you ever need to know about jQuery is [here](http://api.jquery.com)

Comment: thanks...it helps me...now i im implementing your code to index.php to be working...thanks again..i will post here my result soon.

Comment: i have use php to echo links: <a href="ftp://<?php echo $source . '/' . $source2 . '/' . $genre . '/' . $title ?>" id="PopUpItUp" class="detail" data-title="<?php echo $title; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $title ?> (Episodes)</a> then i have copy <script> </script> between <head> in index.php and save file, upload it to server..refresh page click on movie link to see if cookie is set...and cookie is not set...where i have doing it wrong?

Comment: make sure `<script>` is after loading jquery? also, The current code doesn't use cookies

Comment: <html>            
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script>                                                              
    here goes your code of jquery                                                          </script>
</head>

Comment: <a href="ftp://<?php echo $source ?>/<?php echo $source2; ?>/<?php echo $genre ?>/<?php echo $title ?>" id="PopUpItUp" class="detail" data-title="<?php echo $title; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $title ?> (Episodes)</a>

Comment: this is what i have inserted in index.php i checked if hitcounter is increment and is not...so i im doing is wrong somewhere because hit counter does not increment by 1...count.php get id of and increment in mysql database hits using id received from index.php. do i need to put in jquery script function(data-id) and the it wil work?

Comment: Make sure it is also after your declaration of `addHit()` function

Comment: it does not increment hit counter after i put it after addHit()...can you write here your email? i will then send you whole index.php to get point of view where and how to fix this..if you have time..:)

Comment: ok...i have now write html code inside javascript function popup..so does anyone know how can i transfer value pf javascript function to php variable? for example: function doPopItUp(title)     i want now to have php variable $title value of javascript title. $title=title

Comment: can it be done to write javascript value to tmp file and then read tmp file with php variable? sounds easy...but code is needed...so then we don't need ajax call

Comment: i have now successfully send the ajax to the external php file and in external file i echo $_GET['title']; and it works...it echo the value send from index.php using ajax...then i put alert box on success and it alerts OK box..so ajax is sending....then i put alert(data)..on success: $('#popup').html('<div>' + data + '</div>'); and it alerts me form div to /div from external php file but how to show popup window that is defined as hidden in external file form div to /div?

Comment: http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/  this plugin i im using...and ajax function is successfully now i see that i can load content from external php file (there is hidden popup <div> </div>) and example 4a show how to load i have this code here: $('#popup').bPopup({
    contentContainer: data,
    loadUrl: 'http://mysiteaddress.com/popup.php' //Uses jQuery.load()
    });
   }  so  when i alert data i get all correctly in message box that alerts...<div> ... </div> stuff...then opens bpopup and content of bpopup plugin needs to be data from external file..but its contents is empty...someone have solution?

Comment: i have fixed it now..than you all for help (vortextangent) it now sends ajax post to popup.php in php get id from ajax call, then index.php receive data and insert received data in middle of <div> </div> that calls bpopup jquery plugin...i have removed div from popups.php so that i don't get two bpopups only one...so all is now working perfectly..but...i im getting about 1second delay from ajax call is that normal? can it be faster? Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help, if you could accept my answer I would appreciate it.   The delay is something you may have to live with because of the time the server takes to process your ajax request.  You could try to anticipate the user's actions and call the ajax `onhover`, cancel the request if it has not completed `onmouseout` and show the popup `onclick` but it would probably cause more traffic than it's worth.  You can also try to optimize your code a bit but i think this would be a separate question.

Comment: Thanks...i think with optimization of code it will take around 0.8sec (now it takes around 1.0sec) so as you say it's not worth to code more complex code to be faster 0.2sec..:) i will stay on that code...because it is working perfectly. Thanks.